# Can current in a wire from a battery be called a thermodynamic quantity

Tags: thermodynamics, magnetic-fields, electric-current

Joining a metal wire to both ends of a bettery causes current to flow through it.
Also, the flowing current in turn produces magnetic field that kind of rotates around that wire.

Can we call this current, and the subsequent magnetic field, **thermodynamic quantities**?

$\underline{Thermodynamic\space quantities}$ are those quantities that characterises the state of a system. For example, temperature, pressure, number of particles, volume, magnetisation etc.
What I think is - when current is passing through the wire, it causes Joule heating. Resulting in a temperature $T=i^2Rt$. And since temperate is a thermodynamic quantity, its defining quantity "current" should be a thermodynamic quantity also.
But produced magnetic field has no such function. So it is not a thermodynamic quantity.

What should be the correct answer?

Edit: After hyportnex's comment, I realized I have mistakenly written $T$ as *temperature*, whereas the correct word is *heat generated*.

Comment: to clear away some confusion, in the equation $T=i^2Rt$ under the usual notation that the symbols $i,R,t$ mean current, resistance, and elapsed time, resp., the variable $T$ is not the temperature of anything but rather the dissipated heat in the resistor. If you want to know what its temperature is doing then you need more information, such as, the resistor's heat capacity and the way it is embedded in its thermal environment.

Comment: I suspect there is no particular consensus on whether and where terms like "thermodynamic quantity" or "function of state" should be used for non-equilibrium steady states, such the current in a wire connected to a battery. How and where thermodynamics can be extended to such systems is an area of active research. For the term "thermodynamic quantity" I would guess that most people would assume the term implies thermodynamic equilibrium, but I wouldn't want to swear to that (I can easily see people interpreting it as relating to the thermodynamic limit for example).